# Specify function parameter in jest mocking

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am currently writing unit tests to improve my coverage and I am stuck on a function where I want to set the input parameter of a function.

The function I want to test is:

```
this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, (event: any) => {
    if (
      event.values_.name === 'name'
    ) {
      this.openWeatherData(event.values_.name);
    } //more logic ...
  });
```

I want to test the code inside the callback function to test if the correct calls are made.

But how do I set the event parameter to something like

```
{ values_ : { name: 'name' } }
```

and execute the actual callback implementation to improve my coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to create a mock version for `this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel()` method and its mocked implementation. The mocked implementation accept two paramters: `pixel` and `callback`. Invoke the `callback` function manually with your mocked event object.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
export const obj = {
  map: {
    // simulate real implementation
    forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, callback) {
      callback();
    },
  },
  method(e) {
    this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, (event: any) => {
      if (event.values_.name === 'name') {
        console.log('openWeatherData');
      }
    });
  },
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { obj } from './';

describe('67818053', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mEvent = { values_: { name: 'name' } };
    const forEachFeatureAtPixelSpy = jest
      .spyOn(obj.map, 'forEachFeatureAtPixel')
      .mockImplementationOnce((pixel, callback) => {
        callback(mEvent);
      });
    obj.method({ pixel: '12' });
    expect(forEachFeatureAtPixelSpy).toBeCalledWith('12', expect.any(Function));
    forEachFeatureAtPixelSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67818053/index.test.ts (8.297 s)
  67818053
    ✓ should pass (14 ms)

  console.log
    openWeatherData

      at examples/67818053/index.ts:11:17

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.055 s
```